# How to declare variable in triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

Upon creating a trigger i get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

This is my query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reserved BEFORE INSERT ON Reserv
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DECLARE trip_id integer;
    DECLARE free integer;
    DECLARE count integer;

    set @free := (select place_free from Trips where id = trip_id);
    set @count := (select count from inserted);

    if @count <= @free
        begin

            update Trips set place_free = @free - @count where id = @trip_id;

        end
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            return;
        END
 END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: i using mysql..

Comment: Where are you setting trip_id?  As written, I would expect @free to always be null.

Comment: Lots of things wrong here 1) an if must have a then 2) begin and end in and if block are not required in mysql 3) An implicit or explicit commit (ie the rollback is not allowed in a trigger 4) a return is not allowed in a trigger 5) every if must have an end if 6) you are declaring variables but not using them (@free is not the declared variable) 7) you may not be setting delimiters 8) not an error but to avoid confusion with the count function I would avoid using count as a variable name,

Answer (score 2):

What I see is that you are using the `RETURN` statement. As https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions states:

> The RETURN statement is not permitted in triggers, which cannot return
>   a value. To exit a trigger immediately, use the LEAVE statement.

But from my point of view this is a different topic, as the error message speaks of a syntax error in line 3. Maybe you forgot to set the delimiter to something different than `;`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ...
```